# BroadCast Receiver android equivalent in iphone

Tags: iphone, broadcastreceiver, sip, android-broadcast

I am working on a project in iphone where server sends a SIP message as broadcast and it should be received at the client side by the broadcast receiver class as in Android.content.broadcastreceiver

Plz tell me how to receive the broadcasts from the server ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

A summary is as follows:

- You register your app to use APN (apple push notifications)
- When you want to notify the client of something the server needs to send a message to the APN server (in a specific non-SIP format)
- The APN server then informs the client (the iPhone) and you can program the phone to act accordingly within the usual heavy apple limitations.

As for using SIP, it depends on what you actually need to do once you receive the notification but I suspect you will have trouble.